# Variable Data binding WPF cell styles - Object inside a object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

The issue I am currently facing is creating a cell style which can be applied to each column but using a different variable.

Currently i am having to repeat the style code and change one variable, as seen below:

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="CR Implement" Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.End_Date, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"  Width= "90" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle >
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="16" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.StatusInfo}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.MultiBooking}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.status}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.status}" Value="2">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.status}" Value="3">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.isLateValue}" Value="1" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.status}" Value="0" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.isLateValue}" Value="0" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding CRIMPLEMENTATION.status}" Value="0" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

This XAML is currently repeated 30 times for each individual column.

The only variability within each cell style and data grid text column is: the variable name.

The Below code snippets are to give a clearer overview of how the classes are setup.

**C# Class:**

```
  public class Job
{
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }

    public int JobID { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<String, List<Booking>> MyBookings = new Dictionary<String, List<Booking>>();

    public Dictionary<String, List<String>> Emails = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public Booking MilestoneCRBriefAvailable { get; set; }
    public Booking MilestoneCRQuoted { get; set; }
    public Booking MilestoneCRQuoteApproved { get; set; }
}
```

**C# Class**:

```
  public class Booking
{

    public int isLateValue { get; set; } = 0;
    public string StatusInfo { get; set; }
    public string Counter { get; set; }
    public int BKGID { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int CMPID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Start_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End_Date { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
```

The ideal scenario would be change the hardcoded variable in the example

```
CRIMPLEMENTATION.end_date
```

To

```
****.end_date
```

Any Suggestions would be a massive help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind value of a datatrigger.

Offhand I can't think how you could do this elegantly with a converter. You could pass index of the column in but it'd be really fragile.

How I sometimes do "awkward" stuff like this is dynamically build the columns with xamlreader.parse. I build a string which is the base column markup. I then change that ( in the string ) and parse it into a column which I add to the datagrid.

Rather than pull your code apart I'll show you some I have which I can just paste.

I want an enum to drive the columns ( and rows ) I have the user edit values for. This is actually force red vs force blue and attack values for red infantry vs red infantry, red infantry vs blue light infantry and so on.

There are therefore two attack matrices and a usercontrol used twice.
I build the columns:

```
public partial class AttackMatrixView : UserControl
{
    public Sides AttackingSide = Sides.Red;
    public Sides DefendingSide = Sides.Blue;
    public AttackMatrixView()
    {
        Resources.Add("AttackerSide", AttackingSide);
        Resources.Add("DefenderSide", DefendingSide);
        InitializeComponent();
        XElement col = GetXElement(@"pack://application:,,,/Views/AttackFactors/attackFactorColumn.txt");
        foreach (UnitTypes ut in  Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitTypes)).Cast<UnitTypes>().Where(x=>x.ThisFights()==true).Select(x=>x).ToList())
        {
            XElement el = new XElement(col);
            string colString = el.ToString()
                .Replace("^^^Index^^^", ((int)ut).ToString())
                .Replace("^^^EnumString^^^", ut.ToString())
                .Replace("^^^EnumDescription^^^", ut.ToDescriptionString());
            ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
            context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
            context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
            DataGridTextColumn tc = (DataGridTextColumn)XamlReader.Parse(colString, context);
            dg.Columns.Add(tc);
        };

    }
    private XElement GetXElement(string uri)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
        var xmltxt = Application.GetContentStream(new Uri(uri));
        string elfull = new StreamReader(xmltxt.Stream).ReadToEnd();
        xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(elfull);
        return xmlDoc.Root;
    }
}
```

That uses a txt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Factor[^^^Index^^^], Mode=TwoWay,      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"  
xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:UILib;assembly=UILib"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScenarioEditor"
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ModelLib;assembly=ModelLib"
>
 <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <ui:IconParent Height="20" Width="30" 
                 ui:IconParent.IPType="{x:Static model:UnitTypes.^^^EnumString^^^}"
                 ui:Icon.UnitType="{x:Static model:UnitTypes.^^^EnumString^^^}"
                 ui:Icon.Side="{Binding DataContext.DefenderSide
                    , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                >
            <ui:IconParent.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    ^^^EnumDescription^^^
                </ToolTip>
            </ui:IconParent.ToolTip>
                <ui:UnitIcon Margin="2"/>
        </ui:IconParent>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

You could have something similar and manipulate the value for datatrigger, what's bound etc etc.

Just for clarity - the finished view with the two instances of attackmatrix:
[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would cause problems more problems in other areas though. As the data is actually read in from multiple database. we have quite a lot of functionality already implemented into the grid.

I think this would take a total rebuild to successfully implement your solution.

Thank you for you're amazing answer though!